# Rails Ownership of records in many to many relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I’m creating a Rails application and I’m having trouble regarding ownership of a record.

I have a many to many relationship and I would like to find the owner/creator of a record.

Models :

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_accounts
 has_many :accounts, through :user_accounts
end

class UserAccount < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :account
end

class Account < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :user_accounts
 has_many :users, through :user_accounts
end
```

How could I find the User that actually created the Account ?

I’ve thought about adding a `owner_id` field in Account with a belongs_to relationship (e.g. : belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'User' ), but I wanted to know if there was any other way or better way to achieve that ?

Comment: Adding `owner_id` seems like the way to go for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you proposed (adding `owner_id` to `Account`) is a perfectly valid one. Here's a few more.

Add `primary` or `owner` boolean into `UserAccount`. Since you already have a reference to account, it might be better to use that instead of adding another relation.

Another (!dangerous!, but) with no additional columns would be to look for the earliest `UserAccount` according to `created_at` or similar. I suggest against this though, because any data migration you might do down the line might break this.